# Sending XML with POST Request

Tags: python

> I'm newer in python.
> I'm trying to send to send a xml file using HTTP POST request with a body and i received this error:

````
```
````

> b'\r\nxmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">\r\n  \r\n  >1\r\n  XMLSyntaxE
> ```

I used Python 3.7.
Here is my code:

```
import http.client
import base64
import urllib.request
import urllib.response
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
    file = 'sendInvoices.xml'
    headers = {
        # Request headers
        'aade-user-id': 'stergos73',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'c3d8fbf2eb984942a20f9b181139fc4c',
    }
    
    params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    })
    
    try:
        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('mydata-dev.azure-api.net')
        conn.request("POST", "/SendIncomeClassification?%s" % params, file, headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        data = response.read()
        print(data)
        conn.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))`enter code here`
```

> 

Here my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InvoicesDoc xmlns="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0/InvoicesDoc-v0.6.xsd" xmlns:icls="https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/incomeClassificaton/v1.0" xmlns:ecls="https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/expensesClassificaton/v1.0">
            <invoice>
                <issuer>
                    <vatNumber>1xxxxxxxxx</vatNumber>
                    <country>GR</country>
                    <branch>1</branch>                
                </issuer>
                <counterpart>
                    <vatNumber>0xxxxxxxxx</vatNumber>
                    <country>GR</country>
                    <branch>0</branch>            
                    <address>                
                        <postalCode>22222</postalCode>
                        <city>IRAKLIO</city>
                    </address>
                </counterpart>
                <invoiceHeader>
                    <series>A</series>
                    <aa>101</aa>
                    <issueDate>2020-04-08</issueDate>
                    <invoiceType>5.1</invoiceType>
                    <currency>EUR</currency>
                    <correlatedInvoices>400000020342040</correlatedInvoices>
                </invoiceHeader>
                <paymentMethods>
                    <paymentMethodDetails>
                        <type>3</type>
                        <amount>1760.00</amount>
                        <paymentMethodInfo>Payment Method Info...</paymentMethodInfo>
                    </paymentMethodDetails>
                </paymentMethods>
                <invoiceDetails>
                    <lineNumber>1</lineNumber>
                    <netValue>1000.00</netValue>
                    <vatCategory>1</vatCategory>
                    <vatAmount>240.00</vatAmount>           
                    <incomeClassification>
                        <icls:classificationType>E3_561_001</icls:classificationType>
                        <icls:classificationCategory>category1_2</icls:classificationCategory>
                        <icls:amount>1000.00</icls:amount>
                    </incomeClassification>
                </invoiceDetails>
                <invoiceDetails>            
                    <lineNumber>2</lineNumber>     
                    <netValue>500.00</netValue>
                    <vatCategory>1</vatCategory>
                    <vatAmount>120.00</vatAmount>
                    <discountOption>true</discountOption>           
                    <incomeClassification>
                        <icls:classificationType>E3_561_001</icls:classificationType>
                        <icls:classificationCategory>category1_3</icls:classificationCategory>
                        <icls:amount>500.00</icls:amount>
                    </incomeClassification>
                </invoiceDetails>       
                <invoiceSummary>
                    <totalNetValue>1500.00</totalNetValue>
                    <totalVatAmount>360.00</totalVatAmount>
                    <totalWithheldAmount>00.00</totalWithheldAmount>
                    <totalFeesAmount>0.00</totalFeesAmount>
                    <totalStampDutyAmount>0.00</totalStampDutyAmount>
                    <totalOtherTaxesAmount>0.00</totalOtherTaxesAmount>
                    <totalDeductionsAmount>0.00</totalDeductionsAmount>
                    <totalGrossValue>1860.00</totalGrossValue>
                    <incomeClassification>
                        <icls:classificationType>E3_561_001</icls:classificationType>
                        <icls:classificationCategory>category1_2</icls:classificationCategory>
                        <icls:amount>1000.00</icls:amount>              
                    </incomeClassification>
                        <incomeClassification>
                        <icls:classificationType>E3_561_001</icls:classificationType>
                        <icls:classificationCategory>category1_3</icls:classificationCategory>
                        <icls:amount>500.00</icls:amount>               
                    </incomeClassification>
                </invoiceSummary>
            </invoice>
        </InvoicesDoc>
```

Comment: Your error message is not clear, is your XML misformatted?

Comment: Please show a minimal XML (which doesn’t work) that you’re putting in the body.

Comment: Are you putting the file name or its contents in the body as `data=file`? Your code doesn’t seem to read the file.

Comment: You're posting just the filename when you should be posting the contents of your XML file. I'm guessing your server's reporting an XMLSyntaxError exception (which you've truncated) as it is trying to parse `'sendInvoices.xml'` as an XML string.

Comment: The error is statusCode>XMLSyntaxError. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.